# getting an error while hiiting an api in postman and if i think parser_classes creating some mess

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, postman

@detail_route(methods=['put'], parser_classes=[FileUploadParser])
def avatar(self, request, pk=None):

```
    file = request.data.get('file', None)

    if not file:
        print('f')
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    user = request.user
    user.avatar_image.save(file.name, file)
    user.save(update_fields={'avatar_image'})
    generate_all_aliases(user.avatar_image, include_global=False)
    return Response(AuthenticatedUserSerializer(request.user).data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcAT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use request.FILES.get() method to read file from request**
  `file = request.FILES.get('blogPhotos')`